# casting data split to integer

Tags: c#, casting

i realize that it does not read inside `if (berjaya[23].Equals(70))` as if it was not equal to 70. but when i tried to show `berjaya[23]` using MessageBox, it do appear 70.

my first guess is casting. i tried `int value = (int)(berjaya[23]);` and my next plan is try do `if(value == 70)` but it says string cannot be convert to int.

is there any other way for the `(berjaya[23].Equals(70))` be read?

===EDIT===

i should casting the data split by this way:

```
int.TryParse(berjaya[23], out value1);
```

then to change the picture, i used this:

```
if (value1 == 301)
                {
                    Bitmap abc = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\HospitalIcon\\web\\web2\\images\\a3_01.gif");
                    pictureBox1.Image = abc;                                      
                }
```

Comment: You loaded a bitmap, after that just assign that bitmap to a PictureBox or other control for bitmap display and you are done

Comment: **where** do you want to change that image ?

Comment: there are several pictures, insects body part. the user will click the picture for example at the eyes of the insects. this picture will change to new picture. this new picture will sent a new tag number to the server and the server need to change the picture same as in the android application done by the user. @Tigran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but set the image names

```
Bitmap abc = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\HospitalIcon\\fafa\\images\\a3_00.gif");
if (berjaya[23].Equals(70)) 
{

    abc = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\HospitalIcon\\fafa\\images\\a3_01.gif");                    

}

myPicturebox.Image = abc;
```

Comment: it still the same. nothing change

Comment: or set the image of your picture box to null and reload, or check if your image box has a refresh() property

Comment: i already put the refresh() for the myPicturebox..yet it wont change when it equals to 70..i also try put the picture box null then reload..the result still the same

Answer (score 0):

You must add first a Empty bitmap.
like:

```
Bitmap abc;
```

Or you can assign value for that. Then in if/else you change into:

```
abc = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\HospitalIcon\\fafa\\images\\a3_01.gif");
```

Additonal:
Ops, sorry Miss/Mr/Ms (What must I say?) Sara Brown, That will be a much complicated. add this function

```
public int value(string num){
    string a = num.split("");//If this function true?
    int res = 0;
    for(var b = 0; b<a.Length; b++){
        res = res*10;
        switch(a[b]){
            case "0":
                break;
            case "1":
                res += 1;
                break;
            case "2":
                res += 2;
                break;
            case "3":
                res += 3;
                break;
            case "4":
                res += 4;
                break;
            case "5":
                res += 5;
                break;
            case "6":
                res += 6;
                break;
            case "7":
                res += 7;
                break;
            case "8":
                res += 8;
                break;
            case "9":
                res += 9;
                break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

the add this code
    Bitmap abc;

```
if(value(Berjaya[23])==70){
    abc = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Pictures\\HospitalIcon\\fafa\\images\\a3_01.gif");
}
```

Comment: thanks but its already been done and it does change. but what i need is it only change when the value is equal to a number. but what it did was, it always change no matter what the value is.